# How to pass an instance to a function within a component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If the terms used in question are incorrect please bare with me as this is the first time i'm using react js. I have written some code by referring lot of blogs, youtube, docs etc. and now i'm stuck since it is a mix of everything.

I have a requirement where i make a get call to an endpoint (**about.js** component) which returns json data which will be passed to (**workspace.js** component) where it is rendered and displayed. so far it is working fine.

next step, there is a link 'delete'(in cards element of workspace.js) on clicking, it should make a post call to an endpoint with the project_name. here i'm unable to make it work (confused with const, functions etc).

below is the code : (**about.js**)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import "./About.css";
import axios from "axios";
import Account from "./Workspace";
function About() {
  const [resp_data, setdata] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const axios = require("axios");
    axios({
      method: "get",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/projects/",
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        setdata(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {});
  }, []);

  if (resp_data != "") {
    return (
      <div>
        <Account user={resp_data} />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }
}

export default About;
```

**workspace.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";

const Account = (props) => {
  function handleClick(event) {
    alert(event);
    //need to get the project_name here
    //make post call to an endpoint with project_name as data
  }
  const users = props.user.data;
  return (
    <div>
      {users.map((user) => (
        <div className="card-rows">
          <Card className="card" key={user.Id}>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>
                <b>Project : </b>
                {user.project_name}
              </Card.Title>
              <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                <b>DataSet : </b>
                {user.dataset_name}
              </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                <b>DataType : </b>
                {user.data_type}
              </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Link
                href="#"
                name="hello"
                className="delete"
                onClick={this.handleClick({user.project_name})} // call handleclick and the projectname should be available within the function
              >
                Delete
              </Card.Link>
              <Card.Link href="/launch" className="launch">
                Launch
              </Card.Link>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Account;
```

it would be a great assistance if anyone could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in an functional component, you can get the `user` prop by adding curl braces. Also modify your `onClick`.
[React onClick Event Handling](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onclick-event-handling-with-examples#:%7E:text=In%20React%2C%20the%20onClick%20handler,Function%20After%20Clicking%20a%20Button)

I would recommend you to go through [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) thoroughly if starting out.

This should work for you.

```
const Account = ({user}) => { 
//use curly braces around props to fetch user prop

function handleClick(project_name) {
    alert(project_name);
    //need to get the project_name here
    //make post call to an endpoint with project_name as data
}


return(
... //above code
<Card.Link
    href="#"
    name="hello"
    className="delete"
    onClick={() => handleClick(user.project_name)}  
>
    Delete
</Card.Link>
... //below
)
```

Comment: How can i add event.preventDefault(); in my handleClick function?

Comment: Unless it is something that's make a reload like a form or a `<a>` link you do not need to `e.preventDefault()`; If you want to do client side navigation use https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Thanks much Shreyas

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your implementation lies here

```
onClick={this.handleClick({user.project_name})}
```

because this would make the call while component gets rendered. But the react synthetic event handlers expect a function reference to be passed.

In order to achieve the same You can simply convert the `onClick` handler for `Delete` button

from

```
onClick={this.handleClick({user.project_name})}
```

to

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick(user.project_name)}
```

That would look like below

```
<Card.Link
  href="#"
  name="hello"
  className="delete"
  onClick={() => 
    this.handleClick(user.project_name)}>
   Delete
</Card.Link>
```

So, directly the `handleClick` method would receive the `project_name`.

```
const handleClick = project_name => {
    console.log(projectName);
    //You can use `project_name ` for making the API call.
  }
```

Comment: thanks Nithesh for the reply.But this solution results in TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined.  Shreyas Jadhav's answer worked for me

Comment: There was a typo while copying the code from question. I have updated the answer. the change to be made was converting from `function handleClick(event) {` to `const handleClick = project_name => {`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is how you are handing the `onClick` function in the `Card.Link` component.

`OnClick` functions take a function to handle the event. So right now you are just invoking a function but that wouldnt have any effect on the event that is implicitly being passed into the component.

More can be found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

```js
     <Card.Link
      href="#"
      name="hello"
      className="delete"
      onClick={() => this.handleClick({user.project_name})} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your time herman. I tried this, but it results in : Unexpected token, expected "," error. but Shreyas Jadhav's answer worked for me